# Three.js: BufferAttribute or Float32Attribute?

Tags: three.js

[This example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader) shows 500 transparent triangles being rendered. The code uses  `new THREE.Float32Attribute( triangles * 3 * 4, 4 );`

Am I correct that the latest and greatest way is to use a `THREE.BufferAttribute` instead of the `Float32Attribute`?

Also, 
The transparent property is set in the `THREE.RawShaderMaterial` however, opacity is not set anywhere.

I would think that this would be because the color values are set in a loop, with the fourth color value standing for opacity but all of the triangles are consistently transparent (without any varying as I can tell).

I am just not perceiving things correctly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In this `RawShaderMaterial` [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader), you could write it like so:

```
var colors = new Float32Array( triangles * 3 * 4 );

for ( var i = 0, l = triangles * 3 * 4; i < l; i += 4 ) {

    colors[ i     ] = Math.random();
    colors[ i + 1 ] = Math.random();
    colors[ i + 2 ] = Math.random();
    colors[ i + 3 ] = Math.random();

}

geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 4 ) );
```

`colors[ i + 3 ]` contains the alpha value, and is passed to the fragment shader as a varying:

```
varying vec4 vColor;
```

three.js r.73

Comment: The first comment in this https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5098 makes me think that the `Float32Array` is either removed or will be.  Are both ways to declare the attribute equally acceptable?

Comment: It seems the answer to your question can be found in [this thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7611). : - )